# Recursive solution for Permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Hey I have a problem where I need to create two functions, countWithPerms() and ignorePerms() These two functions must be a recursive solution. countWithPerms() will count the number of actual permutations while ignorePerms() will only count the number of duplicate permutations.

So an example would be find the permutation for the number 3. So if I pass 3 into the function countWithPerms() would find that 3 = (2 + 1) = (1 + 2) = (1 + 1 + 1), so countWithPerms(3) is 3, because it counted 3 ways to sum up 3. While countIgnorePerms(3) is 2 because (1 + 2) and (2 + 1), would both not be counted in countWithPerms since they are the just written in the opposite order.

A large example would be countWithPerms(7) is 63, while countIgnorePerms(7) is 14.

I have countwithPerms done, but I am completely stuck on countIgnorePerms.

```
 int countWithPerms( int n)
 {
     if(n == 1)
           return 0;
     else
           n--;
     return (countWithPerms(n) + 1) + 
            (countWithPerms(n));
}

    int ignorePerms(int sum, int xmin){
    if(sum == 1)
           return 0;

        else
        for(int i=0; i<sum;i++){
            sum += sum-xmin;
            2*ignorePerms(sum,xmin)+1;

                 return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are counting partitions, not permutations.

Comment: ignorePerms() is called [integer partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) and countWithPerms() is called [composition of integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(number_theory)).

Comment: I think you are counting operation at the place of permutation.

Comment: Assuming your function is correct, you really should simplify the return statement to `2*countWithPerms(n)+1` - you currently have an exponential rather than linear algorithm.

Comment: @Dukeling: actually for the "with permutations" version the answer is a trivial closed form (just consider n `1` and count in how many different ways you can place "barriers" in the `n-1` locations between a digit and the next)...

Answer (score 1):

The idea of counting without considering permutations is to consider only ordered solutions.

To do this pass in addition to `n` also what is the minimum value `xmin` that an addendum must have. For example

```
3 = 1 + 2
```

would be ok (because 2 >= 1), but

```
3 = 2 + 1
```

wouldn't be acceptable (because 1 < 2).

So the idea is to write a function that answers "how many sums with non-decreasing terms can give the prescribed `total` in the first addendum is not less than `min_addendum`?".

1. if `min_addendum` is bigger than `total` clearly the answer is 0
2. if `total` is 1 then there's only one sum
3. otherwise the first possible sum is `total`, then you should count as sums

   - `min_addendum` + a sum of other non-decreasing terms, the first not less than `min_addendum` totalling `total-min_addendum`
   - `min_addendum+1` + a sum of other non-decreasing terms, the first not less than `min_addendum+1` totalling `total-min_addendum-1`
   - `min_addendum+2` + a sum of other non-decreasing terms, the first not less than `min_addendum+2` totalling `total-min_addendum-2`
   - ...

Comment: What would xmin need to be set as? n-1?

Comment: Initially you pass it as 0 (because you can accept any addendum as first) and in recursive call you need instead to pass the value you just added (to ensure that the sequence is ordered).

Comment: Hmm Im still a little confused, So I'm passing in n after it has been evaulted but how dose the function know n must be < then previous calculated n

Comment: @AaronB: I wrote a sketch of a possible solution. In the proposed sketch however the initial value for `xmin` is 1, not 0. More than this is just C code... you don't want that, right? :-)

Comment: dam I dont even feel like im close... posted what i have so far in edit

Comment: Haha I think im getting closer now, When i do ignorePerms(7) i get 14 which is the right answer, but ignorePerms(3) is = 6

Comment: @AaronB: I'm sorry but your code is very very far from a correct solution. For example do you realize that `2*ignorePerms(sum,xmin)+1;` does absolutely nothing? The previous line has a `;` so this line is an expression on its own that is computed and whose result is thrown away.